# Sizzle.js Uncaught TypeError undefined (reading 'expr')

Tags: javascript

```
  $.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function (n, i, m) {
    return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
  };
```

.expr isn't defined.

I have added a CDN just incase

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sizzle/2.2.1/sizzle.js"></script>
```

Cant see why expr would not be defined if the script is included in the header?

Error Being:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'expr')
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.8 the API for this changed, the jQuery 1.8+ version of this would be:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```